# Regex - two specific digits followed by optional digits

Tags: regex

I'm trying to create a regex for the following pattern:

- starts with two specific digits (e.g. `((50)|(51)|(52))`)
- may be followed by any amount of digits

Examples:

- `50` matches
- `523412` matches
- `53` doesn't match
- `54234` doesn't match

I managed to create this

```
^((50)|(51)|(52))+[0-9]+?$
```

but it doesn't match cases like `50` or `51`. It works only when it's followed by at least one digit.

Comment: `5[012][0-9]*` should do to match 0 to +Inf possibles digits after 50,51 or 52. In brief, do some search and learning on regex quantifiers characters `+`, `*`, `?`.

Comment: Your regex does not work because of `+?` quantifier that requires at least 1 char. Use `*`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following should work;

`^(50|51|52)[0-9]*$`

This matches 50, 51, or 52 at the start of the string, and then any amount of digits thereafter. You were pretty close to having it working.

[Here's a working example](https://regex101.com/r/Gjlq8w/2)

---

Good suggestion by [Tensibai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3627607/tensibai)

`^5[012][0-9]*$`

This matches the number 5 at the start of the string, followed by either 0, 1, or 2 - and then again any amount of digits thereafter.

[Here's a working example for this solution](https://regex101.com/r/RRvbOL/2)

Comment: It works, thank you! Unfortunately, I can't follow the suggestion as there are more combinations of available two digits which don't start with 5. I'll keep that in mind, though.